# CSS Transitions for rapidly changing positions

Tags: javascript, css

I have some `div`s whose position (top and left values) changes somewhat rapidly with JavaScript. These changes are in 1px increments, but I'd like the changes to be smooth - the 1px increments are too jagged for my liking. I've tried using a CSS transition with a very short animation time (.1s, for example) but its still somewhat jumpy and the position can still change before the transition animation is complete.

Is there a way to make these changes butter-smooth?

Comment: Can't assume it. Create a demo or past your snippet in question.

Comment: unless you post code i cannot advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it can help, but I would maybe try using 'em' units (instad of px) so you can use less than 1px values (at least it generally works with text size,  for ex.). Also, do not do transitions with top/left properies. Instead, use translate3d > it will do the same job but generally better and faster (triggers hardware acceleration). Some scss mixins that can help:

```
@mixin single_transition($property:all, $speed:300ms, $ease:ease-out) {
  -webkit-transition: $property $speed $ease;
  -moz-transition: $property $speed $ease;
  transition: $property $speed $ease;
}

@mixin remove_transition{
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

@mixin translate($x:0, $y:0){
  -webkit-transform: translate($x, $y);
  -moz-transform: translate($x, $y);
  -ms-transform: translate($x, $y);
  -o-transform: translate($x, $y);
  transform: translate($x, $y);
}

@mixin translate3D($x:0, $y:0, $z:0){
  -webkit-transform: translate3d($x, $y, $z);
  transform: translate3d($x, $y, $z);
}

@mixin remove_translate{
  -webkit-transform: none;
  -moz-transform: none;
  -ms-transform: none;
  -o-transform: none;
  transform: none;
}
```

Usually, I apply both translate and translate3D, so where available, translate3d will be used, otherwise translate.
Anyway, translate3d is currently well supported.

Hope it helps!

Edit:

If you won't succeed in doing what you want, you can also try to get it with some animation library. Currently some of the best I think are:

http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

http://julian.com/research/velocity/

http://lvivski.com/anima/

http://greensock.com/ (paid)

Comment: While not directly resolving my issue, you did bring my attention to using translate instead - much smoother already. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to control `top` and `left` within JavaScript. You need to add a `transition: all` on your css class in order to change `top` and `left` with JS and have those properties animated.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/tupepu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

If the increments are that small, incrementally update the `style` attribute of the HTML element using javascript instead of relying on CSS transitions.

[Parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/)' web page does this. To see it in action, open the web inspector on that page.

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score -2):

Try to use the setInterval() function.

Comment: To do what? I'm not doing anything on a set interval - the positions are changing based on user input. I'd like to smooth out the positional jumps.

Comment: this is terrible advice, you should be using setTimout or if you don't need backwards compatibility requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: @MatthewRath Or better yet, `requestAnimationFrame` with a `setTimeout`-based polyfill.